# datetime insertion in SQLite database using QT and parameters

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, parameters

I am trying to perform an insertion into a SQLite database from a c++/QT application.
One of the columns of the table where I want to insert the data is a datetime (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).

I have try to use this code:

```
...
query.prepare("INSERT INTO table (table_date_time, ...) "
        " VALUES (?, ...);");
query.bindValue(0, "datetime('2004-12-11 13:00:00', '+1 day')");
...
```

but it inserts the text "datetime('2004-12-11 13:00:00', '+1 day')" instead the value 2004-12-12 13:00:00.
If I try

```
...
query.prepare("INSERT INTO table (table_date_time, ...) "
        " VALUES (datetime(?), ...);");
query.bindValue(0, "2004-12-11 13:00:00, +1 day");
...
```

or

```
...
query.prepare("INSERT INTO table (table_date_time, ...) "
        " VALUES (datetime(?), ...);");
query.bindValue(0, "'2004-12-11 13:00:00',' +1 day'");
...
```

the datetime field does not get filled.
What is the correct way to use datetime functions allong parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this problem only from Java/Android; over there it's not possible to use the datetime() function through the wrapper. I always ended up just storing the Unix timestamp as an integer, doing the date manipulation in the application -- if all else fails, you may consider doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bound value only replaces one parameter, the 2 parameters to the `datetime` function have to be sent separately:

```
query.prepare("INSERT INTO table (table_date_time, ...) "
        " VALUES (datetime(?, ?), ...)");
query.bindValue(0, "2004-12-11 13:00:00");
query.bindValue(1, "+1 day");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `QDateTime`, you can achieve similar results.

```
query.prepare("INSERT INTO table (table_date_time, ...) "
        " VALUES (:datetime, ...)");
QDateTime timestamp = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
timestamp.addDays(1);
// Qt::ISODate format...
query.bindValue(":datetime", timestamp);// 2017-09-05T11:50:39
// Custom format
query.bindValue(":datetime", timestamp.toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));  // same as above but without the T
```

Note that `QDateTime` to `QVariant` to `QString` for a text field in sqlite yields a default format of "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss".

See [Qt::ISODate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#DateFormat-enum) and [QDateTime::toString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString).